# Front end JS fetch(POST) request being sent as a GET?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

So this fetch request is called on the submit button.

For some reason, in the dev tools, it goes through as a GET. Tested the request in Insomnia, and it ends up returning the site to me (the handlebars site)... and none of my console logs ever show up (on the backend or the front)

**Front End**

```js
const newPostSubmit= async function(event) {
    console.log('didnt make it');
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('made it');

    const title = document.getElementById('post-title').value;
    const content = document.getElementById('content').value;

    const response = await fetch(`/api/posts/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title,
            content
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Post Success!')
        // document.location.replace('/dashboard');
    } else {
        alert(response.statusText);
    }
}

document.getElementById('submit-post').addEventListener('submit', newPostSubmit);
```

**Back End Route To Be Used**

```js
router.post('/', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body
    console.log(body);

    Post.create({ ...body, userId: req.session.userId })
    .then(dbPostData => {
        console.log(dbPostData);
        res.json(dbPostData)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: The code provided definitely sends the JSON as a POST request

Comment: If your code is being redirected, it will show up as a GET request

Comment: Why is the fetch using `/api/posts` but the endpoint is `/`?

Comment: Yeah so it's the chrome dev tools network tab that's showing it as a GET. And yeah it seems correct to me, so it's being redirected?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the code is modular, there's middleware that gets you to that JS file that has the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my HTML. The id of 'submit-post' was placed on the button, but needed to be on the form itself (the button was within the  element) which is why the function would never run